# If $X \sim U[-1,1]$, show that $X$ and $X^2$ are uncorrelated but not independent

Tags: probability, independence, uniform-distribution, correlation

$X = $Unif[-1,1] RV. Show X and $X^2$ are uncorrelated but not independent

I think I did something wrong cause $E[X^3]=E[X]E[X^2]$.
$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{1-(-1)}=\frac1{2}$

$E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_X(x)dx$

$E[X\times X^2]=E[X^3]=\int_{-1}^1\frac{x}2\frac{x^2}4dx=\frac18-\frac18$
$E[X]=\int_{-1}^1\frac{x}2dx=0$
$E[X^2]=\int_{-1}^1\frac{x^2}4=\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{12}=\frac1{6}$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: $\operatorname{E}[X^n]=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{2} x^n dx $

Comment: Oh, but I think that you believe you did something wrong because you got that $\operatorname{E}[X^3] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] \operatorname{E}[X]$. That is true, not an error. But that doesn’t imply that they are independent.

Comment: How do I prove they're independent? Sorry I was mistaken and though if $E[X^3]=E[X]*E[X^2]$ then they're independent, but that just means uncorrelated

Comment: You can show that their joint PDF is not the product of their individual PDFs. Alternatively, you could show something like that $P(X^2 >1/4 | -1/2 < X < 1/2) \neq P(X^2 >1/4) P(-1/2 < X < 1/2)$.

Comment: How would you calculate their joint?

Comment: Now that you ask, I see that their joint distribution would be singular, since $X^2$ is a deterministic function of $X$. You could use the joint CDF, by computing the values of $X$ that could satisfy both intervals of $X<a$ and $X^2 < b$, then computing that probability. But I think the alternative approach is much simpler.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760116/if-x-uni-1-1-show-that-x-and-x2-are-not-independent?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the comment above to make some corrections. However it is true that $EXEX^{2}=EX^{3}$. What this says is that the covariance of $X$ and $X^{2}$ is $0$ (as you were required to prove). This does not imply that $X$ and $X^{2} $ are independent. To prove that they are  not  independent assume that they are and get a contradiction. If they are independent the so are $X^{2}$ and $X^{2}$. (In fact $f(X)$ and $X^{2}$ would be independent for  any measurable function $f$). But then $EX^{2}EX^{2}=EX^{4}$ You can see that this is not satisfied.

Comment: Could you explain how $X^2$ not being independent to itself shows X and $X^2$ are not independent?

Comment: @user8714896 In general independence of $X$ and $Y$ implies that of $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ for any measurable functions $f,g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. [This follows immediately from definition of independence: $P(f(X)\in A)=P(X \in f^{-1}(A))$ etc )]. I am taking $f(x)=x^{2}$ and $g(x)=x$.